# Extending from more classes

Tags: java, android

```
...
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);    
    }

    //other methods where I make use of ListActivity
}
```

I get "Interface expected here" error on "implements AppCompactActivity".
I've already read many posts reguarding similar issues where it's been said to create an interface, but I can't really figure out how to do it on my code.

Comment: AppCompatActivity is a class not interface

Answer (score -1, accepted):

AppCompatActivity is a class , just extend AppCompatActivity , add a recyclerview in your layout and implement the viewholder and adapter for the recyclerview

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);    

           Recyclerview list = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);
           //set adapter
        }

        //other methods where I make use of ListActivity
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can't. Java doesn't support multiple inheritance, like c++ does. In your case you don't need to extend both `AppCompatActivity` and `ListActivity` . You can extend `AppCompatActivity`, and put a `ListView` in your xml. You will need to call `setAdapter`, on the `ListView` instance instead of `setListAdapter`, and you will need to set explicitly an onItemClickListener for your ListView